# I can't understand what is the instructor tried to solve in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just started learning programming (in js) on Lynda and I was going alright until the instructor started coding this

```
var amount =0;

//create index
var i=1;

//check condition
while (i<=10){
    amount += 100;
    //increment index   
    i++;
}

alert ("The value is: "+ amount);
```

From what I'm understanding I am just trying to add 100 ten times, can't I just say 100*10 or

```
var amount = 100;
amount*10;
alert ("The value is: "+ amount);
```

Note: I'm sorry I don't fully understand the site's rules as I'm new here so if I made any mistake please correct me

Comment: use `amount=amount*10`

Comment: @Alexandru-lonut Mihai Ok but does this solve the same problem as the instructor's code or did he want to solve another problem, I mean I don't understand the problem that he is trying to solve, if it's adding 100 ten times then why the index and the loop?

Comment: It's just an example...

Comment: @Goliadkin Ok thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the goal is not to multiply the amount but this is only an example to show you the use of the while loop.

Comment: Aha, Ok thanks a lot, but I understood right, the code is trying too multiply the amount but 10 but with using a while loop right? Thanks :)

Comment: There are two methods of obtaining result. 1000 can be obtained by 10*100 or 100+100+...+100 by ten times.

Answer (score 0):

You can have

```
var amount= 100*10;
```

If the goal is to have the variable 'amount' equal to 10 times 100, then that would work. Otherwise, I am assuming the assignment was to get you used to while loops and the basics of javascript. Could you provide a link to the course?

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I think now that he was just giving an example of a loop and mentioning the <= symbol.
https://www.lynda.com/Programming-Foundations-tutorials/Writing-while-statement/83603/90459-4.html
This is the video in the course.